# Apply a Filter to a Camera video stream publishing to Media Server

Tags: apache-flex, video-streaming, video-capture, video-processing, flash-media-server

I am Trying to Apply some information Like text and An Image as an overlay to create a overlay effect as lice a security camera with time and date on the video along with a png based Logo.

I can record  VIDEO Using Flex and FMS or any other Media Server. But I want to save a modified version of the stream being uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Use camTwist (mac) or webcammax (pc) as your video input...you can use that program to use the webcam and then add whatever over it (text, date). Use Flash Media Live Encoder and select camTwist as your video source. Stream and save your recordings using that FMLE.

Answer (score 1):

Sorenson Squeeze is pretty awesome for this and is cross platform. Camtwist is cool but it's not really a 'pro' app, that makes me sound way snobbish. It's actually pretty fun and a good suggestion for a simple result but I haven't found anything better than Sorenson Squeeze for the features and control it gives you.

Comment: they should pay me a commission for that glowing review.. ;-)